# OneDrive - Laptop syncs fine but not desktop

Tags: onedrive

I have Windows 10 on both my laptop and desktop.

I can drag a file on my laptop to the Explorer OneDrive folder and it shows up in onedrive.live.com. I can also drag a folder to onedrive.live.com and it shows up in the laptop's local OneDrive folder.

However neither operation works on my desktop computer.  On my desktop I can see any new files added on my laptop show up in the browser at onedrive.live.com.

Is there a OneDrive setting somewhere to tell it to automatically sync?
There is no such setting in the onedrive.live.com settings and I cannot find where any local OneDrive setting on my desktop are located.

Answer (score 1):

There was no icon for OneDrive in my notification area. I went to %localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive, right-clicked on OneDrive.exe and selected "Send to Desktop" This not only put a OneDrive icon on my desktop, it also added one to the notification area AND it came up with a dialog box for logging into OneDrive. As soon as I logged in, the files on onedrive.live.com started showing up in the OneDrive local folder.